# Spring Java Config: all beans are created despite constructor only requiring certain beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have an interface and several different classes that extend the interface which take different constructor arguments (e.g. a String and an int, or two Strings and an int). I also have a Config class that creates the beans to inject into the constructor. The bean names match the parameter names (I have also tried using the @Qualifier annotation). However, when an instance of a class is created it looks as though Spring is creating instances of all beans even though the constructor may only require 2 or 3 arguments.

Because the beans are created via a method that reads a file line by line and alters the line once the appropriate text has been read, the beans being created do not contain the right String or int. I can't change this method.

Is there a way to call the constructor and specify which beans are created?

I can't post the code as this is part of an assignment.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a configuration with your bean and being explicit

```java
@Configuration
public class Configuration
{
    @Bean
    public MyInterface myBean()
    {
        new ConcreteImplementationOfMyInterface();
    }

}
```